# Publishers: Identifiers & Imprints

Tags: companies, publishing, publications

I have a list of ca. 300 (academic) publishers entailing their commonly used names, such as *Taylor & Francis*.

There are two problems now:

1.) **Imprints**: Some are imprints of other publishers. For instance, *Routledge* is an imprint of *Taylor & Francis*.

2.) **Names**: Sometimes I am unsure about the correct name. For example, is it *Springer*, *Springer Publishing*, *Springer Science+Business Media* or *Springer Nature* (whereby the latter might be an imprint of *Springer*)?

Thus, my question is:
Are there any open data that could disambiguate names of publishers, show (persistent?) identifiers, and detect relations between imprints and their overarching companies?

This would greatly facilitate the task (in comparison to manual research).